# I/O optimized port completion framework

Tags: c++, windows, networking, tcp, udp

I need some good I/O completion framework for Windows that supports both TCP/UDP.
I found this: http://www.serverframework.com/ but prices are too far from my budget limit.

Comment: What specific features are missing from the one Windows comes with?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I dont know it, #Andrew Finnell: thanks will check them.

Comment: [Windows has I/O completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx), as well as the simpler approach using completion callbacks with `ReadFileEx` and `WriteFileEx`, `WSARecv`, `WSARecvFrom`, `WSASend`, `WSASendTo`.  Very powerful, and I usually find using them is simpler than any of the wrapper APIs.  (wrappers have their place in providing portability across many OSes, of course)

Comment: Why do you need a framework?  If it's a question of the complexity of the API then I can probably help you out with it if you have specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try the free version of The Server Framework which you can download from here: http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html

This has been used by 1000s of developers over the past 10 years and works well and, despite being unsupported, has no outstanding bug reports on it. It doesn't have all of the features available in The Server Framework but it IS within your budget ;)